# On the integration of the euclidean norm

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How to show  that $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\|x\|^{\alpha}}$ is integrable on the unit ball $B(0,1)$ of $\mathbb{{R}}^{d}$ if and only if ${\alpha < d}$ (where $\|{\cdot}\|$ represents the Euclidian norm)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community, I edited my question. I hope that is more clear now

Comment: You can use polar coordinates to get the exact value for the integral.

Comment: But here we are in R^d and not R^2

Comment: @Mounira He meets the polar coordinates in the $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Answer (score 0):

**Necessaty ($\Rightarrow$):** First, let's show that if
$f(x)$ is integrable, then $\alpha <d$. We consider the integral over $B=B(0,1)$

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\int_B  \frac{dx}{\|x\|^\alpha} & = \int_0^1 \int_{S^{d-1}} \frac{1}{r^\alpha} r^{d-1} d \sigma dr \\
 & = \int_0^1 r^{d-1-\alpha} dr \int_{S^{d-1}} d\sigma\\
&= \sigma (S^{d-1}) \int_0^1 r^{d-1-\alpha} dr\\
&= \sigma (S^{d-1}) \left[\frac{r^{d-\alpha}}{d-\alpha}\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{\sigma (S^{d-1})}{d-\alpha},
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\sigma (S^{d-1})$ is the surface measure of the unit sphere $S^{d-1}$. Notice that this integral is finite iff $d-\alpha >0$, which implies $\alpha <d$.

**Sufficiency ($\Leftarrow$) :** Assume $\alpha <d$, and do the same calculations above to obtain $f(x)$ is integrable, i.e. the integration of the absolute value over the ball B is finite.